# Ambiguous Method Names: Same method name and parameters different return value

Tags: c#, overloading

I am getting the compile error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties
>   getXmlNodeValue.

I have 3 methods all with the same name and parameters, these 3 methods do however have 3 different return types (`double`, `int` and `string`). Is it possible to have 3 methods with the same name and parameters but different return types?

If not, what method would you suggest I use? Ie, just change the method names to `getXmlNodeText`, `getXmlNodeDouble`, etc. or something else?

```
private static string getXmlNodeText(XmlNode node, string xPath, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
{
    try
    {
        return node.SelectSingleNode(xPath, nsmgr).InnerText;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public static string getXmlNodeValue(XmlNode node, string xPath, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
{
    return getXmlNodeText(node, xPath, nsmgr);
}

public static double getXmlNodeValue(XmlNode node, string xPath, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
{
    return Convert.ToDouble(getXmlNodeText(node, xPath, nsmgr));
}

public static int getXmlNodeValue(XmlNode node, string xPath, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(getXmlNodeText(node, xPath, nsmgr));
}

// Usage problem:
string name = getXmlNodeValue(pitNode, "ns:name", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Sounds like a good way to do it: getXmlNodeDouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, different return type does not constitute an overload. You're better off renaming the methods with a convention that includes the return type name.

Another approach is to use generics to make the typing flexible.
More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

use generics as shown below to get the desired type value.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value1 = GetValue<Int16>("23");
        double value2 = GetValue<double>("23.34");
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(string value)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
```